# Location not being updated automatically

Tags: android, android-location

I'm implementing LocationListener in my Fragment class and used the following code to keep track of location updates, although it's not get frequent updates as it should. I need to show users position on map like Google Navigator.

Find the best provider

```
mLocationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

// if I uncomment the next line, it takes too long to get the location
// criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
// if I leave the line above commented, the app seems to receiving location from triangulation

mProvider = mLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnowLocation(mProvider);
```

LocationChanged event

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    setMapCameraPosition(latLng);
}
```

Comment: Are you using a MapView to show the user position?

Comment: I'm using Google Maps Android API v2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only asking for the last known location, which may or may not exist. In order to use the LocationListener you must call one of the [`requestLocationUpdates()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29) methods.

```
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(mProvider, 0, 0, mLocationListener);
```

Comment: Id like to add that using a small filter that only updates the user location if the new location is more accurate (newLocation.getAccuracy() <= oldLocation.getAccuracy() + mAccuracyTolerance) could prove more worthy than using a Criteria filter for accuracy only.

Comment: @Machinarius When I had the accuracy not set, the application was using only triangulation instead of GPS.

Comment: @Sam actually I'm using mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(mProvider, 1000, 1, this) from the onResume method.

Comment: Ok, how often is it updating and how far are you traveling?